# No suitable provider for component - Buckminster

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, buckminster

I'm trying to build my eclipse plugin with Buckminster but there is 
this problem. When I try to resolve and materialize my cquery file, jenkins shows
me the error message:

```
ERROR   [0001] : No suitable provider for component ScDt:eclipse.feature was found in resourceMap file:/C:/Users/jvlk/.jenkins/jobs/Aragorn/workspace/scDt/scdes.rmap
  ERROR   [0001] : No suitable provider for component ScDt:eclipse.feature was found in searchPath resources
    ERROR   [0001] : Resolution attempt ended with exception: Provider local(file:///C:/Users/jvlk/.jenkins/jobs/Aragorn/workspace/ScDt/): Missing CSpec source required by component type eclipse.feature
      ERROR   Provider local(file:///C:/Users/jvlk/.jenkins/jobs/Aragorn/workspace/ScDt/): Missing CSpec source required by component type eclipse.feature
```

I'm using repository available on url: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo.
My rmap looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rmap
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/RMap-1.0"
    xmlns:bc="http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/Common-1.0"
    xmlns:mp="http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/MavenProvider-1.0"
    xmlns:pp="http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/PDEMapProvider-1.0">

    <searchPath name="resources">
        <provider readerType="local" componentTypes="osgi.bundle,eclipse.feature" mutable="true" source="true">
            <uri format="file:///{0}/{1}/">
                <bc:propertyRef key="workspace.root" />
                <bc:propertyRef key="buckminster.component" />
            </uri>
        </provider>
    </searchPath>

    <locator searchPathRef="resources"/>

</rmap>
```

Do you have any proposal? I will be grateful for any

Answer (score -2):

Try the buckminster forum at eclipse.org for getting help